# Read and write a PNG file using libpng in C

Tags: c, png, libpng

My goal is to read a PNG file, change the pixel values and store the updated PNG file using [libpng](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/libpng).

I wrote two functions called `read_png` and `write_png` by following the [official libpng manual](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng-manual.txt). The example code doesn't change the pixel values, because it's a [minimum, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It also doesn't check if the input file is actually a PNG file.

```
#include <png.h>

png_infop info_ptr;
png_bytepp row_pointers;

void read_png(char *file_name)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(file_name, "rb");
    png_structp png_ptr = png_create_read_struct(PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    png_infop info_ptr = png_create_info_struct(png_ptr);
    png_init_io(png_ptr, fp);
    png_read_png(png_ptr, info_ptr, PNG_TRANSFORM_IDENTITY, NULL);
    row_pointers = png_get_rows(png_ptr, info_ptr);
    png_destroy_read_struct(&png_ptr, &info_ptr, NULL);
    fclose(fp);
}

void write_png(char *file_name)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(file_name, "wb");
    png_structp png_ptr = png_create_write_struct(PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    png_init_io(png_ptr, fp);
    png_set_rows(png_ptr, info_ptr, row_pointers);
    png_write_png(png_ptr, info_ptr, PNG_TRANSFORM_IDENTITY, NULL);
    png_destroy_write_struct(&png_ptr, &info_ptr);
    fclose(fp);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    read_png(argv[1]);
    write_png(argv[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

The code compiles without any errors.

```
$ gcc -o rw_png -lpng rw_png.c
```

And the program can be run with two arguments.

```
$ ./rw_png input.png output.png
```

The problem is, that although `output.png` is created, it's an empty file instead of a PNG file.

```
$ file output.png
output.png: empty
```

Comment: Time to step through in a debugger and find out why.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

libpng uses `info_struct` to keep around information about what the pixel data looks like. So you need to keep it around for `write_png` (or recreate it).

```
png_infop info_ptr;  // <-- Global info_ptr (good)
png_bytepp row_pointers; 

void read_png(char *file_name)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(file_name, "rb");
    png_structp png_ptr = png_create_read_struct(PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    png_infop info_ptr = png_create_info_struct(png_ptr);  // <-- creating a new, local info_ptr 
    png_init_io(png_ptr, fp);
    png_read_png(png_ptr, info_ptr, PNG_TRANSFORM_IDENTITY, NULL);
    row_pointers = png_get_rows(png_ptr, info_ptr);
    png_destroy_read_struct(&png_ptr, &info_ptr, NULL); // <-- destroying the info_ptr (as well).
    fclose(fp);
}
```

So, a fixed `read_png` would be:

```
void read_png(char *file_name)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(file_name, "rb");
    png_structp png_ptr = png_create_read_struct(PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    info_ptr = png_create_info_struct(png_ptr);  
    png_init_io(png_ptr, fp);
    png_read_png(png_ptr, info_ptr, PNG_TRANSFORM_IDENTITY, NULL);
    row_pointers = png_get_rows(png_ptr, info_ptr);
    png_destroy_read_struct(&png_ptr, NULL, NULL); 
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Assuming a `read_png` / `write_png`, you'll free `info_ptr` in `write_png`.